# How to scatter (draw) on basemap in an streaming manner in Ipython Notepbook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to scatter some points on basemap, using python in IPython notebook. I need to show it in interactive mode. But, it just show the map, and when I stop running the cell, it shows a second plot with points scattered across it.  How can I do it on a interactive basemap ? Is there a better option rather than using basemap.

Here is the code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from pylab import rcParams
import numpy as np
import time

llon = -140
ulon = 140
llat = -50
ulat = 70
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (14,10)
my_map = Basemap(projection='merc',
            resolution = 'l', area_thresh = 1000.0,
            llcrnrlon=llon, llcrnrlat=llat, #min longitude (llcrnrlon) and latitude (llcrnrlat)
            urcrnrlon=ulon, urcrnrlat=ulat) #max longitude (urcrnrlon) and latitude (urcrnrlat)

my_map.drawcoastlines()
my_map.drawcountries()
my_map.drawmapboundary()
my_map.fillcontinents(color = 'white', alpha = 0.3)
#my_map.shadedrelief()



plt.pause(0.0001)
plt.show()


colors = plt.get_cmap('jet')(np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 5))
i=0
j=0
while True:
    xs,ys = my_map(i, j)
    my_map.scatter(xs, ys,  marker='o', alpha = 0.5,color=colors[0])
    plt.pause(0.0001)
    plt.draw()
    time.sleep(5)
    i=i+10
    j=j+10
```

[image]